# Non-dynamic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Let's say I have the models `Post`, `Category`, `Tag`.

All of these should reference a relationship to any of the following "states": `Local`, `National`, `International`.

I could of course, in a traditional manner, create a model for those and the other models could reference each of it's IDs.

But I want something more "reliable" than the generated ID for a record.

My thinking this far is to reference the (unique) title instead.

Is there any convention for this scenario?

Comment: If the "state" is just an enumeration type with values "Local", "National", and "International", you could define the type in the `app/models/concerns` directory and reference the type in each of `Post`, `Category` and `Tag` as choices for an attribute value. If, over time, the choices for "states" could change, then a table holding the values might make more sense.

Comment: Which rails version are you using?

Comment: @BroiSatse I'm on latest version, 4.1.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I would do:

Create a module:

```
module RegionRange    # Please, choose better name
  inlcuded do
    enum :region, [:local, :national, :international]
  end
end
```

Write a migration:

```
add_column :posts, :region, :string
add_column :categories, :region, :string
add_column :tags, :region, :string
```

Include module into your classes.

`ActiveRecord::Enum` has been added in rails 4.1 and it will create a number of very useful methods like `local?`, `national!` (wills set the region to :national) as well as creates scopes for each value (`Tag.international`). Having it wrapped in the module enforces all the modules has always same set of possible values.

If you prefer (I think I would) you can use integer column instead of string. Check this website for how to do this: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 1):

One option (if you don't need much states) is to map ids/keywords with your states in a mapping hash object (put into a module lib or even a separate class - e.g. app/models/concerns).
Normalizing states out into a states table makes sense from DB perspective, but can come with some performance issues (extra joins/ queries/ ActiveRecord model object instantiations are required, which mostly does not contain any business logic, only for getting the state).
Since states become more and more complex during development, another option is to choose one of the existing well tested state machine gems like [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'd want to look into [Single Table Inheritance](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance) - although I don't understand your specific question regarding not calling an ID (I'll explain in a second)

From looking at it a little deeper, here's what I'd be looking at:

```
#app/models/state.rb
Class State < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | type_id | stateable_id | stateable_type | x | y | z | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :type
   belongs_to :stateable, polymorphic: true

   delegate :name, to: :type
end

#app/models/type.rb
Class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | name | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :states
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :states, as: :stateable
end
```

Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but keeps the structure extensible & modular.

--

**Relational**

When you mention you want something more "reliable" than generating an ID, you have to appreciate that the ID's you generate will be [`primary_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key):

> In database relational modeling and implementation, a unique key is
>   the attribute or a set of concatenated attributes in an entity whose
>   value(s) guarantee only one tuple (row) exists for each unique value.
>   The primary key has to consist of attributes that cannot be
>   collectively duplicated by any other row.

This means that if you're concerned about the different ID's generated by Rails, you have to consider the way the relational database structure works. You *should* have a single reference to data ([Single Source of Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth)), meaning that if you reference that, you'll get access to the specific data you have stored

In your case, this might not be relevant; but I wanted to give you the idea anyway... you may wish to use a [`uuid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) instead (seems there's a [new gem for it here](https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid)):

```
#app/models/your_model.rb
Class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :create_uuid
   private

   def create_uuid
      self.uuid = loop do
        random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
        break random_token unless ModelName.exists?(token: random_token)
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: class keyword is not "Class". STI is not an appropriate solution for states.